# Sending email through without mail account set up?

Tags: ios, email

I am making a booking app for a restaurant and I am wondering if there is any way to send an email through for a booking without the user having to have any email address set up?

I essentially want to be able to send the user selections from my app with the simple press of a "submit button" How do I ma age this?

Comment: "if there is any way to send an email through for a booking without the user having to have any email address set up?" - but that is totally absurd!!!!

Comment: Without email account setup, you have to use SMTP way or create your webservice hosted then use that webService.

Comment: What, are you asking me to rephrase myself?

Comment: yes @tyt_g207 solution and you can use gmail SMTP for that as-well

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for here.  My best guess is you're wanting to send email without having the SMTP and other information configured on the device?  Edit your question and let us know what you're really trying to do and what you've already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a webservice to send the email to the user. I have used this in an app to provide a feedback form - while we were testing we found that quite a few users that needed help didn't have email setup on their device, so couldn't actually tell us there was a problem!

You can either roll your own webservice, or there are several providers that offer this. I ended up using http://www.mailgun.com/